# input textbox sentences into array automatically

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

please view the code from Microsoft for translation array :

```
var from = "en";
        var to = "es";
        var translateArraySourceTexts = textbox.Text.Split(new Char[] { '.' });
        var uri = "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/TranslateArray";
        var body = "<TranslateArrayRequest>" +
                       "<AppId />" +
                       "<From>{0}</From>" +
                       "<Options>" +
                       " <Category xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                           "<ContentType xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\">{1}</ContentType>" +
                           "<ReservedFlags xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                           "<State xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                           "<Uri xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                           "<User xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                       "</Options>" +
                       "<Texts>" +
                         **  "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">{2}</string>" +
                          ** "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">{3}</string>" +
                         ** "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">{4}</string>" +
                       "</Texts>" +
                       "<To>{5}</To>" +
                   "</TranslateArrayRequest>";
       ** string requestBody = string.Format(body, from, "text/plain", translateArraySourceTexts[0], translateArraySourceTexts[1], translateArraySourceTexts[2], to);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
            request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authToken);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            switch (response.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                    Console.WriteLine("Request status is OK. Result of translate array method is:");
                    var doc = XDocument.Parse(responseBody);
                    var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2");
                    var sourceTextCounter = 0;
                    foreach (XElement xe in doc.Descendants(ns + "TranslateArrayResponse"))
                    {
                        foreach (var node in xe.Elements(ns + "TranslatedText"))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\nSource text: {0}\nTranslated Text: {1}", translateArraySourceTexts[sourceTextCounter], node.Value);
                        }
                        sourceTextCounter++;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Request status code is: {0}.", response.StatusCode);
                    Console.WriteLine("Request error message: {0}.", responseBody);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please focus on the ** line. I want to translate sentences from the input box, and used "." as an indicator for each sentence.

My question is, in the line code with **, currently only able to detect 3 sentences. If I input more than 3 sentences, the fourth and the rest will not be detected. and if I input less than 3 sentences, there is an error `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

my question is, how to make the system automatically append the array if it detects more sentences and adjust the array automatically? please give me some advice

Answer (score 0):

In your html string, there are spaces for variables defined as {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}.

The line you highlighted is

```
string.Format(body, from, "text/plain", translateArraySourceTexts[0], translateArraySourceTexts[1], translateArraySourceTexts[2], to);
```

It is replacing the  {0} with **`from`**, {1} with **"`text/plain`"**, {2} with **`translateArraySourceTexts[0]`**, {3} with **`translateArraySourceTexts[1]`**, {4} with **`translateArraySourceTexts[2]`**, {5} with **`to`** in that order.

Since you are using only indexes `[0], [1] and [2]` of your text sentences, you are able to append only 3 sentences to document body.

How to solve?

You can input more sentences in your textbox. When you split, translateArraySourceTexts will contain more items. Add more indexes in the body HTML string for more sentences (like {6}, {7}) and then pass your sentences to the body in string.Format as  translateArraySourceTexts[3], translateArraySourceTexts[4]. It will work. It will change to something like mentioned below.

```
string.Format(body, from, "text/plain", translateArraySourceTexts[0], translateArraySourceTexts[1], translateArraySourceTexts[2], translateArraySourceTexts[3], translateArraySourceTexts[4], to);
```

More on string.Format

http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/Help-with-C-Method-with-a-string-and-Multiple-Parameters

**EDIT:**
Since you mention that you can enter many sentences. You already split those sentences and get an array length of, say x. Let's just call this array of sentences as **sentences**. Create an object array of size x+3. So, if you enter 4 sentences, create an object array of 7.

```
object[] dataArr = new object[x+3]
```

You are already creating **`<string tags>` string** inside **`<Texts>` xml node** already. *You will need as many strings as sentences have been entered. In this case, you would need 4 `<string tags>` strings in `<Texts>` part, each with incrementing placeholder for value like {2}, {3}, {4} and so on.*
Now, populate this dataArr.

```
dataArr[0] = from;
dataArr[1] = "text/plain";  
dataArr[dataArr.Length - 1] = to;

for(var i=2; i < dataArr.Length - 1; i++)
{
 dataArr[i] = sentences[i-2];  
}
```

and pass **dataArr** to **string.Format**

```
string.Format(body,dataArr)
```

Comment: ok I understand, but the problem is I can't predict how many sentences that user will input. So I need to have the system that able to anticipate no matter how many sentences input from user.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using C# 6, string interpolation and LINQ will work.** String.Format() limits what you can do here.

**String interpolation** (a string preceded by a ***$*** for a single line or ***$@*** for multiple lines) lets you insert data directly into the string simply by surrounding your variable expression with **{}**... which **will make it easier for you to do something like this...**

```
       var contentType = "text/plain";
       var body = $@"<TranslateArrayRequest>
                   <AppId />
                   <From>{from}</From>
                   <Options>
                   <Category xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />
                       <ContentType xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\">{contentType}</ContentType>
                       <ReservedFlags xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />
                       <State xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />
                       <Uri xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />
                       <User xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />
                   </Options>
                   <Texts>{String.Join("\r",translatedArraySourceTexts.Select(s=>$"<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">{s}</string>"))}</Texts>
                   <To>{to}</To>
               </TranslateArrayRequest>";
```

Here's how it works:

1. Place your body into a multiline string using $@ to make it a bit easier to understand (and the compiler work a little less :) )
2. Insert your variables directly into the string, surrounded by {}
3. When you get to the  tags, replace the contents with this`{String.Join("\r",translatedArraySourceTexts.Select(s=>$"<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">{s}</string>"))}`

Starting from the inside: **it uses LINQ to Select() each sentence** and insert it **into your**  tags using nested string interpolation `($"<string... {s}</string>")`, and then **String.Join() combines the results** into one string separated by carriage return.

Again, this only works with C# 6.0

You can find more on string interpolation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx).